# Does Resharper support code analysis for css files from CDN? (avoid unkown css class warning)

Tags: css, visual-studio-2017, intellisense, resharper-9.0

Is there a way to make R# code analysis work when using an external css file?

e.g if i include the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Resharper does not recognize the classes from the css.

Therefore I Resharper complains with the blue squiggly line complaing about "**unkwon css class**" for all class from the remote cdn.

[image]

I know that I could add a copy of the file to my project.

However is this really the only way?

Comment: Hi Postlagerkarte, after you included the link reference, have you tried to build/rebuild the solution? For the VS default intellisense, if we use the online css file, we need to build the solution to make the intellisense recognize the online css file content like this: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Atv5QNuFrncKmCd2H7uRF-CVYioO. For the Resharper issue, you can also go to the Resharper community forum: https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366389-ReSharper-Community to seek for a more professional support.